# JavaFX.ListView with Styled Cells display duplicate lists (Java)

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

I am using JavaFX for a simple project at my University. 
I have to create a view with 2 columns, where on the left we can select a course and, on the right, we see students currently subscripted to it.

For this all work okay, then I have to make the ListView's cells background colored differently for selected cells.

In order to accomplish this, I extended the class 'ListCell < T >' creating the following.

```
public class StyledSelectableCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {
    private Background selBG;
    private Background idleBG;
    private Paint idleTextCol;
    private Paint selTextCol;

    public StyledSelectableCell(Colors idleBG) {
        assert idleBG.getComplementary() != null;
        this.selBG = new Background(new BackgroundFill(idleBG.getComplementary().getVal(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
        this.idleBG = new Background(new BackgroundFill(idleBG.getVal(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

        this.idleTextCol = idleBG.getSuggestedTextColor();
        this.selTextCol = idleBG.getComplementary().getSuggestedTextColor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(item == null) return;

        if(this.isSelected()) {
            setBG(this.selBG);
            setTextFill(this.selTextCol);
        }
        else {
            setBG(this.idleBG);
            setTextFill(this.idleTextCol);
        }

        setText(item.toString());
    }

    private void setBG(Background c){
        this.setBackground(c);
    }
}
```

And then, in the main application class, I've included this code:

```
// Creating 2 observable lists
        ObservableList<Student> studentList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Course> courseList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(courses);

        // Creating listview for stuxents and courses
        ListView<Course> courseLv = new ListView<>(courseList);
        ListView<Student> studentLv = new ListView<>(studentList);


        // Setting custom colored cells
        // TODO bug only present with this two methods uncommented
        courseLv.setCellFactory(
                courseListView -> new StyledSelectableCell<>(STUD_COL)
        );

        studentLv.setCellFactory(
                studentListView -> new StyledSelectableCell<>(COUR_COL)
        );

        VBox studentSelection = new VBox();
        studentSelection.getChildren().add(studentLv);

        VBox courseSelection = new VBox();
        courseSelection.getChildren().add(courseLv);

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.addColumn(1, studentSelection);
        pane.addColumn(0, courseSelection);

        courseLv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, course, t1) -> {
            studentList.clear();
            studentList.addAll(t1.getStudents());
        });
```

When I start the program all goes fine, I click on the first course and the students appear correctly.
The problem is at the second click when I choose another course, it displays students repeated twice at the end, in reversed order ( really strange ).

This picture shows the situation at the first click:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDLuv.jpg

This is when I select another course and the bug appears:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MWJj.jpg

Comment: If the cell is empty or the item is null, you need to set the text to an empty string (or null), and reset the styles to the default.

Comment: Incidentally, you can do all this directly in CSS, without the need for a `ListCell` subclass at all.